# How to solve the error "base Required session does not exist" in Quickblox?

Tags: android, quickblox

## MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.sll_user.chatapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.quickblox.auth.session.QBSettings;
import com.quickblox.core.QBEntityCallback;
import com.quickblox.core.exception.QBResponseException;
import com.quickblox.users.QBUsers;
import com.quickblox.users.model.QBUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Quickblox Setting
static final String APP_ID = "00000";
static final String AUTH_KEY = "aaaaaaaaaaa";
static final String AUTH_SECRET = "bbbbbbbbbbbbb";
static final String ACCOUNT_KEY = "cccccccccccccccc";

Button btnLogin,btnSignup;
EditText edtUser,edtPassword;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initializeframework();

    btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.main_btnLogin);
    btnSignup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.main_btnSignup);

    edtUser = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.main_editLogin);
    edtPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.main_editPassword);

    btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,SignUpActivity.class));
        }
    });

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String user = edtUser.getText().toString();
            String password = edtPassword.getText().toString();

            final QBUser qbUser = new QBUser(user, password);

            QBUsers.signIn(qbUser).performAsync( new QBEntityCallback<QBUser>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QBUser qbUser, Bundle args) {
                    // success
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(QBResponseException error) {
                    // error
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),""+ error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    });
}

private void initializeframework(){
    QBSettings.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext(),APP_ID,AUTH_KEY,AUTH_SECRET);
    QBSettings.getInstance().setAccountKey(ACCOUNT_KEY);
 }
}
```

### SignUpActivity.java

```
package com.example.sll_user.chatapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.quickblox.auth.QBAuth;
import com.quickblox.auth.session.QBSession;
import com.quickblox.auth.session.QBSettings;
import com.quickblox.core.QBEntityCallback;
import com.quickblox.core.exception.QBResponseException;
import com.quickblox.users.QBUsers;
import com.quickblox.users.model.QBUser;

public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Quickblox Setting
static final String APP_ID = "00000";
static final String AUTH_KEY = "aaaaaaaaaaa";
static final String AUTH_SECRET = "bbbbbbbbbbbbb";
static final String ACCOUNT_KEY = "cccccccccccccccc";

Button btnSignUp, btnCancel;
EditText edtUser, edtPassword;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    QBSettings.getInstance().init(getApplicationContext(),APP_ID,AUTH_KEY,AUTH_SECRET);
    QBSettings.getInstance().setAccountKey(ACCOUNT_KEY);
    registerSession();

    btnSignUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signup_btnSignUp);
    btnCancel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signup_btnCancel);

    edtUser = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.signup_editLogin);
    edtPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.signup_editPassword);




    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String user = edtUser.getText().toString();
            String password = edtPassword.getText().toString();

            final QBUser qbUser = new QBUser (user,password);

            QBUsers.signUp(qbUser).performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBUser>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(QBUser qbUser, Bundle bundle) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Sign Up Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),""+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    });




    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
        }
    });


}

private void registerSession() {
    QBAuth.createSession().performAsync(new QBEntityCallback<QBSession>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QBSession qbSession, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(QBResponseException e) {
            Log.e("Error",e.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
}
```

#### Logcat

```
 08-22 14:41:51.095 8853-8877/com.example.sll_user.chatapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf10638c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xf0fb1d90)
 08-22 14:41:52.941 8853-8877/com.example.sll_user.chatapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf10638c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xf0fb1d90)
 08-22 14:42:00.091 8853-8853/com.example.sll_user.chatapp D/QBASDK:      =========================================================
=== REQUEST ==== 90d50467-906e-4bf4-b385-f4c8b77d2d21 ===
REQUEST
    POST https://api.quickblox.com/login.json
HEADERS
    QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
    QB-SDK=Android 3.3.0
    QB-Token=1fd1a31114b5e8fc0ec390e7a1eff83ac3011d8b
PARAMETERS
    login=
    password=
INLINE
    POST https://api.quickblox.com/login.json?login=&password=
 08-22 14:42:01.043 8853-8853/com.example.sll_user.chatapp D/QBASDK: *********************************************************
*** RESPONSE *** 90d50467-906e-4bf4-b385-f4c8b77d2d21 ***
STATUS : 401 
HEADERS
    Status=401 Unauthorized
    Server=nginx/1.8.1
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
    X-Request-Id=bf9912db-42c2-41b6-95b0-31b126761da6
    X-Content-Type-Options=nosniff
    X-Runtime=0.008429
    WWW-Authenticate=OAuth realm=users
    Connection=Close
    X-Android-Received-Millis=1534920121038
    Date=Wed, 22 Aug 2018 06:41:56 GMT
    QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=0.1.1
    X-Frame-Options=SAMEORIGIN
    X-Android-Selected-Protocol=http/1.1
    Strict-Transport-Security=max-age=31536000
    Cache-Control=no-cache
    X-Android-Response-Source=NETWORK 401
    Set-Cookie=_mkra_ctxt=ec0ec27a8d453e7d5183aaeda6fe5f21--401; path=/; max-age=5; HttpOnly; secure
    X-Android-Sent-Millis=1534920120550
    Content-Length=55
    X-XSS-Protection=1; mode=block
    Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8
BODY
    '{"errors":{"base":["Required session does not exist"]}}'
 08-22 14:42:01.120 8853-8877/com.example.sll_user.chatapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf10638c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xf0fb1d90)
 08-22 14:42:03.053 8853-8877/com.example.sll_user.chatapp D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf10638c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xf0fb1d90)
```

Recently I had tried to build the singIn and signUp function with QuickBlox API. However, when I send the request by clicking the login button, I had received an error message (base Required session does not exist).

I seems that I didn't create a session to bypass the token to the QuickBlox, but isn't the function

```
QBUsers.signIn(qbUser).performAsync( new QBEntityCallback<QBUser>(){}
```

is a write and read session already?

Can anyone help me about that? Thanks

Comment: I had just review the logcat again , seems the token is generated. However, the Quickblox server did not receive that.